# The site ahead contains malware?

Tags: magento-1.9

When I hit the website URL then it shows below security error:

> The site ahead contains malware Attackers currently on example.com
>   might attempt to install dangerous programs on your computer that
>   steal or delete your information (for example, photos, passwords,
>   messages, and credit cards).

I am using 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This may show more information on your specific problem:

https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=YourDomain.com

I've had this happen once before on a site the problem was the Guru Inc infection although that was back in 2015 and store was barely maintained.

See here about that: https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-fix-guruinc-infection/

The malware should be removed and then once this is complete you can submit to google for removal of the warning with Google Webmasters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your server has been infected by some malware code. You need to search and remove it.

Have a check in https://www.magereport.com/ and diagnose your site issue.

It may be you have not updated your sites with security patches. You can either update your site with latest magento version or you can install the patches separately.

You can also refer the below links

https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-protect-your-magento-store-against-brute-force/

https://magento.com/security/best-practices/protect-your-magento-installation-password-guessing-new-update

Answer (score 0):

This is the message i got from google adwords team. Now how to find the js file url in my files ?

Dear Customer,
Thank you for contacting Google Adwords. Hope you are doing well.
Unfortunately our last check which was from 5 hours ago showed us that you still have one link to remove .

Please remove this last malware link to make your ads work .
https://siteverification.online/lib/info.js

If you have other queries, please do not hesitate to contact us or you provide us with a phone number and suitable time frame of your preference within our operating hours (6 am till 3 pm GMT) in order to arrange a call.